# zshell use variable variables to get value in hask tables

Tags: zsh

Make the following function output the same as `echo ${clash[http]}`

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
typeset -A clash=( ["http"]=7890 ["socks"]=7891 )

function getValue() {
    echo ${(P)1}
}

getValue clash http
```

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how you *might* use `$2` in the definition?

Comment: @zhuxiaoxi : Why are you tagging this as sh, shell and bash, when the question is only about Zsh?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
function getValue() {
    typeset -A hashTab=(${(kvP)1})
    echo $hashTab[$2]
}
```